# What a reasonable person should conclude from these circumstances?

Tags: universe, consciousness

He found himself in an universe where he has some special powers compared to other people, but he is not omnipotent. He can affect physical reality but his possibilities are limited. His body does not obey the usual physical laws. A research centre in Vorarlberg, Austria has determined that the state of his body cannot be read exactly, it is somehow hidden from the equipment. They say this may indicate some stream of information comes from outside the universe.

He is smarter than 99% people around him.

He has some history from the past he has learned from recordings and witnesses but he has no memories of that. Evidently a lot of people and rulers wanted to kill him in the past.

He thinks he is immortal because he many times survived situations where the probability of his survival was 1/100000000000 and less but this is only according to his supposed history of which he has no memory.

On the other hand he had suffered injuries which do not cure entirely during his remembered time period.

Comment: "He found himself in an universe" How does he know he's in a different universe? Does he remember a previous universe? What does it mean to read "the state of his body"? How are they concluding it means there's information coming in from the outside? How does he know he's suffered injuries? What do you mean by "do not cure entirely"? Do you mean he has scars? How doe he determine he's "smarter than 99% people around him"?

Comment: Immortal? Infallible?  No clue about his past?  He must conclude he's Donald Trump!

Comment: @Schwern Does he remember a previous universe? - no. This is the only universe he knows.

Comment: @Schwern "What does it mean to read "the state of his body"?" - physical variables  of the state of his body. They are just look uncertain to the apparatus, unlike all other people. "How are they concluding it means there's information coming in from the outside?" - they say it is open to interpretation but seemingly his actions and future state are impredictable given the known physical laws which are working for other people. "How does he know he's suffered injuries?" - he has suffered them and continues suffereing if he is not enough careful.

Comment: @Schwern "Do you mean he has scars?" - yes, but not from the period he does not remember but narrated to him. "How doe he determine he's "smarter than 99% people around him"?" - he passes exams better than 99%, he wins international math contests etc.

Comment: @Anixx If he doesn't remember a previous universe, what does "he found himself in an universe" even mean? We all find ourselves in a universe. What does it mean for a heartbeat to "look uncertain"? Is it like "beat... beat? umm... beat?" "*his actions and future state are impredictable*" everyone's actions and future state are not predictable. You answered "How does he know he's suffered injuries?" by simply stating "he has suffered them". How does he know he suffered them? This conversation only adds to [my conclusion](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/40045/760).

Comment: @Schwern Presumably when he wakes up he cuts himself and discovers he can be injured.

Comment: @Schwern "What does it mean for a heartbeat to "look uncertain"?" - the technonogy is advanced but their equipment is unable to determine the state of his body, especially brain, as opposed to other people.

Comment: "everyone's actions and future state are not predictable." - in this plot it is possible to read the state of physical systems and predict their future up to certain probability. His future cannot be predicted even up to probability, like if its initial state was not possible to determine.

Comment: @Schwern "How does he know he suffered them?" - lol because he has been beaten in the face and got under a car so he had broken leg.

Comment: Dream / intoxication.

Answer (score 2):

A story about a wildly overdone superhuman/chosen-one protagonist can go two ways. If you play it straight up it becomes [a Neil Breen movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KolenE1GCyg) where the whole situation makes no sense and that's the... humor? Pathos? Both? Neither? The meta story of why someone would write a story about an absurdly powerful protagonist with very convenient explanations becomes the story.

Or you can play with the absurdity of the character's powers and explanations for them (as if in some bad movie). Make the central point of the story the character questioning whether this absurdly convenient (for them) reality is real. This is far more interesting and what I'll focus on.

---

A reasonable person would conclude he's a paranoid dissociative compensatory narcissist.

> Seeks to counteract or cancel out deep feelings of inferiority and lack of self-esteem; offsets deficits by creating illusions of being superior, exceptional, admirable, noteworthy; self-worth results from self-enhancement.

[Dissociative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_disorder): He can't remember his past at all. He's possibly in a [dissociative fugue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue_state) playing out a fantasy life.

[Narcissist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder): The whole world revolves around him. A research center is devoted to studying him. He's important enough that "*a lot of people and rulers wanted to kill him*".

[Compensatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensation_%28psychology%29). He thinks he has special powers, but fails to give any specifics. Any failure to demonstrate them or their specifics he claims they're limited. He's "*smarter than 99% of the people around him*" even though "smart" is a subjective measure and he couldn't possibly know the minds of 7 billion people. He thinks he's immortal. He thinks he's survived against impossible odds in the past.

[Paranoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoid_personality_disorder). He thinks the leaders of the world are trying to kill him. He tells doctors they should be able to read "the future state of his body" but that's not a thing doctors can do.

The "disorder" part comes in his convenient and vague explanations for having no explanation. He can't remember his past. He's "*in another universe*" but can't say what that means or what his previous universe was. He believes "*the state of his body cannot be read exactly*" even though that's medical gibberish. He claims to have been examined at "*a research centre in Vorarlberg, Austria*", but [Vorarlberg University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorarlberg_University_of_Applied_Sciences) has no medical program. Nobody can find who told him he's receiving a "*stream of information comes from outside the universe*" or how they concluded that or what that means.

Comment: "He thinks he has special powers, but fails to give any specifics." - he can affect movement of matter. It is measurable. "He thinks he's survived against impossible odds in the past." - this is according the recorded history he is narrated. He does not have a clue but if he believes, this is what happened.

Comment: @Anixx You're going to have to make the parameters of your story and universe a lot clearer. How is this universe different? You'll have to make clear *what he believes* vs *what he does* vs *what actually happens*. It still sounds like a Neil Breen movie, and I think the disorder story is far more interesting.

Comment: "He tells doctors they should be able to read "the future state of his body" and ignores them when they say they can't." - lol, no, its opposite. They think they would be able to do it as usual (as they did on other people) but discover their instruments report gibberish. They named the phenomenon with a complicated scientific term.

Comment: @Anixx "They think they would be able to do it as usual"... that's not usual. You'll have to explain to us how this universe is different. If they can predict the state of people's bodies, you have to put that in your question.

Comment: Well, in short they found his body does not obey the usual physical laws and all the predictive physical theories fail on it.

Comment: Okay but what are the options besides considering himself mad?

Comment: @Anixx "*They found his body does not obey the usual physical laws and all the predictive physical theories fail on it.*" This is too vague. Does light not bounce off him? Does he violate conservation of energy? You need specifics. "*What are the options besides considering himself mad*?" The details don't really matter. He's apparently superhuman. He can: accept that he's an amnesiac super human; consider what he'll do with these powers; decide if he will search for his past; submit himself to scientific testing to advance our knowledge of physics.

Comment: Does light not bounce off him? Does he violate conservation of energy? - neither. There is some "area" inside his body that is not scannable by the instruments. Any instruments they have. Area in quotes because it does not have exact constant spatial localization but it is inside his body. Besides this finding the fact he (according to the history) survived where 99.9999999999999999999999% of others would die is also puzzling (even though nothing provably super-natural has been observed).

Comment: "He's apparently superhuman" - okay. What can be the conclusion? He is playing a simulated universe game with bots? He is god but his powers are somehow hidden? Other theories?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38405/discussion-between-schwern-and-anixx).